# Как правильно отвечать на $http запросы с сервера NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Есть такой простой сервер

```
const express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs');


const app = express();
app.listen(8889);
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var subApp = express();

app.use('/', subApp);

subApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/'), {
    index: 'none'
}));

subApp.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    var mainHtmlPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './public', './index.html');
    fs.readFile(mainHtmlPath, 'utf8', function (err, html) {
        res.send(html);
    });
});


/*=====================================================*/
const book = {
    d: 'Data',
    b: 'Book'
};

app.get('/books', function (req, res) {
    res.send(book);
});
```

Важным из всего кода является  отрывок из кода  после комментария

И есть вот такой контролер AngularJS

```
 app.controller('testHttpCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/books'
    }).then(function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      });
  }])
```

Это я таким образом пытаюсь получить объект

> const book = {...

с сервера...

Но получаю ответ от сервера  вот  такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно отправлять `$http-запросы` на сервер и получать внятный ответ от него?
Почему я получаю в ответ весь документ, а не объект `const book= {`?

> P.S. Знание NodeJS очень скудные и поверхностные, а AjgulsrJS только
>   "грузу"

Comment: Может быть Вам отвечает обработчик `/*`?

Comment: С express не работал, но ... попробуй переместить код отвечающий за обработку books, выше кода отвечающего за обработку '/*' и app.use (/ books...) поменяй на  subapp. .....А вообще, в коде каша... модуль http не нужен, subapp, тоже

Comment: @Дмытрык,  вот что значит, когда тебе помогают в том, в чем не разбираешься...))) Это я о написанном не мной сервере...  Ты оказался прав в обоих вариантах...  Сработало так `subApp.get('/books',...` и перед всеми `subApp(...` , благодарю...